# Sharing data between a library which is part of multiple application

Tags: android

I want to share data between my library which is part of multiple application. Suppose right now app A is open, now I would like to get some data from other apps which have same library. So what will be best way to do this? Here I don't know which other app's on save device have my library. Also I don't want to create a central apk which provide data to all other apps.